# Append a reactive data frame in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a code something like this:

```
for( #loop starts ....
    temp_data_frame <- reactive(d_frame2()[0,]) #only for if i = 1
    temp_data_frame <- reactive(rbind(temp_data_frame(), d_frame2())) 
    )#for loop ends

subset_dataset <-eventReactive(input$go, {temp_data_frame()})
renderDataTable( subset_dataset(), options = list(pageLength = 15))
```

In d_frame2, I am getting new data each time loop is run. I am creating another temp_data_frame with the same column name as d_frame2, so that appending will be easy. Finally, using renderDataTable I am showing the output. 
This code results in this error:

```
evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

I found out that this line: `temp_data_frame <- reactive(rbind(temp_data_frame(), d_frame2()))`
is creating the error. How this can be resolved? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion in your function definition is causing to many (infinite?) evaluations.
What if you remove the line all together? Or rename the 2nd function, so

```
    temp_data_frame2 <- reactive(rbind(temp_data_frame(), d_frame2()))
```

I just had a similar problem with a recursive function.

Comment: Already did that, but if you do so how will the appending work?

Comment: Funny thing is that I had to solve my problem using a for-loop.

Why do you have the first line in there?

Comment: Is it not possible to replace both lines with this single line?

        `temp_data_frame <- reactive(rbind(d_frame2()[0,]), d_frame2()))`

Comment: For the first loop it will work, but for the second loop it will simply replace the values in temp_data_frame, so I can't do the appending.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the situation. Does the user enter the data frames manually with the shiny UI? If so, why is the for-loop necessary? As far as I know every time a user makes a change to the front end the reactive statements are executed. So doesn't it run when you replace the entire for-loop with the 2 lines in it?